# Can Continuity of $f$ imply $f(x)=x$ for some $x$ in the domain?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$(1)$ Let $S \subset R$. Consider the statement: "If $f$ is a continuous function
from $S$ to $S$, then $f(x) = x$ for some $x$."  This statement is true if $S$  equals

(A) $[0, 1]$
  (B) $(0, 1]$
(C) $R$
(D) $[-3,-2] \cup [2, 3]$

***What I attempted:***
I think the answer should be either $[0,1]$ or  $(0,1]$ . Because, I have found examples of functions on $R$ and on $[-3,-2] \cup [2, 3]$ which are continuous but continuity does not imply $f(x)=x$ for some $x$.

However, while I tried think it more deeply, I found that the problem can be easily solved by drawing a square with vertices $(0,0),(1,0), (1,1), (0,1)$. The diagonal line of the square can be considered as a function of form $y=x$. Now consider the question  :

***Can we find a continuous function such that the functional values are only in one of the triangles? That is, is it possible to find $f(x)$ such that none of the functional values touches the line $y=x$ ?***

Of course, we can not find any function on [0,1] so that the none of the functional values (i.e. the values of $y$) touch the line $y=x$. There should exist at least one $x \in [0,1] $ such that $f(x)=x$. However, we can find continuous function on $(0,1]$ such that no functional values touch the line $y=x$.

Therefore the answer should be (A) $[0,1]   $

Am I correct? I think my method is highly intuitive. Is there any flaws in it? Is there any other way to think the same?

Comment: this basically means that $y=x$ intersects graph of $f(x)$. Obviously this is not necessary, i.e. $f(x)=x+1$

Comment: For B you can have an example $f(x) = \frac{x}{2}$, for C the Vasya's example is good

Comment: $[3 , 2] \cup [2,3]$? I'm suspicious...

Comment: Actually it should be$ [-3,-2] \cup [2,3]$. I have edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right the answer is $[0,1]$. You can prove it by applying the intermediate value theorem on $g(x)=f(x)-x$.

Comment: We have, $g(0)=f(0) \ge 0$( Since the range is also [0,1]). Again, $g(1)=f(1)-1 \le 0$. IMV can be applied if $f(0) >0$ and $f(1) <1 $.

Comment: If $f(0)=0$ or $f(1)=1$, the solution follows pretty easily.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct. I think the interviewer would expect the student use IMV rather than the intuitive approach that I used.